# working with empty data points for sma series

Tags: pine-script

I have a very simple indictor script that is calculating sma's of varying lengths on a number of variables. Obviously at the start (ie the left) of the data set, the sma doesn't exist until the minimum number of bars, equal to the period of the SMA has elapsed. When I mouse over the indicator to check the value in this initial period, the value shows as Ø (ie zero with a line through it)... not 0 (ie not "zero") or na

At a later point I actually want to use this SMA data series to do calculations, such as add a number of different period averages together or calculate an average of the values (for example sma period 21 + sma period 55 + sma period 89), I do not get any results for any period prior to the commencement of the sma 89, because the value in that series is empty.

I would like to treat those empty values as zero when adding them...
so up until candle 21, I would expect to see zero.
Between candle 21 and 55 I would see sma 21 value + 0 + 0
between candle 55 and 89, I would see sma 21 value + sma 55 value + 0
and after candle 89, I would see a proper sum of all 3 sma values...

1. Can someone confirm for me how we refer to these values?? they are not "na", or zero, are they "empty" or Null values??
2. is there a way to check for those values in a series, either when declaring the value, or after it is created and replace them with 0 (ie zero)??

`

```
ma1 = ta.sma(ma1abs,21)
ma2 = ta.sma(ma1abs,55)
ma3 = ta.sma(ma1abs,89)
p = (ma1+ma2+ma3)/3
plot(p, style = plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=3, title='av')
```

`

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

`nz` [function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_nz) replaces NaN values with zeros (or given value) in a series.

```
ma1 = nz(ta.sma(ma1abs,21))
ma2 = nz(ta.sma(ma1abs,55))
ma3 = nz(ta.sma(ma1abs,89))
p = (ma1+ma2+ma3)/3
plot(p, style = plot.style_histogram, color=color.new(color.orange, 0), linewidth=3, title='av')
```